# Automapper Mapping Inconsistency

Tags: asp.net, automapper, webapi

I have this class following class. student, studentrequest(Dto) , mapping profile and apicontroller.

i dont know why it is mapping to null value.

```
public class Student : BaseEntity, IAuditableEntity, IDeletableEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameKH { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameEN { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string MotherNameKH { get; set; }
    public string MotherNameEN { get; set; }
    public string FatherNameKH { get; set; }
    public string FatherNameEN { get; set; }
    public string MotherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FatherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CurrentAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}
```

and DTO

```
public class StudentRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameKH { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameEN { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string MotherNameKH { get; set; }
    public string MotherNameEN { get; set; }
    public string FatherNameKH { get; set; }
    public string FatherNameEN { get; set; }
    public string MotherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FatherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CurrentAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Profile

```
 CreateMap<StudentRequest, Student>()
```

My Update Api Controller

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Update(int id, StudentRequest studentRequest)
{
    var student = await _context.Students.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.Id == id);
    if (student == null) return NotFound(new ApiResponse(404, "Student Not Found"));

    student = _mapper.Map<StudentRequest, Student>(studentRequest);
    student.LastModifiedBy = GetCurrentUserName();
    student.LastModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;

    try
    {
        _context.Students.Add(student);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(GetCurrentUserName(), GenerateIPAddress());
        return Ok(new ApiResponse(200, "Succesfully Added Student"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Error Adding Student"));
    }
}
```

this line `student = _mapper.Map<StudentRequest, Student>(studentRequest);`

First student has `CreatedBy`, `CreatedOn`, data already.

but after mapping, `student.CreatedBy = null;`

I dont know what is wrong with this behavoir mapping.

Comment: I dont want to map anything on createdby, createdon. but why it maps exisiting value to null

Answer (score 1):

```cs
studentMapped = _mapper.Map<StudentRequest, Student>(studentRequest); 
student = studentMapped;
```

studentRequest doesn't have a `CreatedBy` property. So `studentMapped.CreatedBy` will be null. And you set it to student.
I think this code might help:

```cs
_mapper.Map<StudentRequest, Student>(studentRequest,student);
```

Comment: this is perfectly. thank you alot. I spend 10h trying to figure it out. but why, it should be just ignore mapping, but it set to null. im so doubtful

Comment: _mapper.Map<StudentRequest, Student>(studentRequest,student);  what is the different between mind and this

Comment: _mapper.Map<S,T>(）will create a new object. _mapper.Map<S,T>(s,t) will map s to t, which would change the t var.